# How do I set Tomcat response buffer size through configuration?

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to change through configuration (afaik server.xml) the default response buffer size. The documentation states that this is possible using the "bufferSize" attribute inside the "Connector" element but this is not working. I also tried to change "socket.appWriteBufSize" and "socket.appReadBufSize" but no luck:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            connectionTimeout="20000"
    bufferSize="64000" 
    maxHttpHeaderSize="64000"
    socket.appWriteBufSize="64000"
    socket.appReadBufSize="64000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Note that if I change the response size from my java code (httpResponse.setBufferSize(64000)) it will work, but for good reason I want to use the standard tomcat configuration mechanism.

All tests were done using a freshly downloaded Tomcat.

Comment: Which Tomcat version?

Comment: And how do you know it is not working?

Comment: "Which Tomcat version?"
As you can see from the date, this happened in 2011. It's difficult for me, as of today, 7 years back. to recall the tomcat version, but as you can see from my answer down there, the buffer size was carved into the code, and there was no way to set it up trough configuration.

Comment: "how do you know it's not working?" Well, as you probably know, you will get a chunked response as the server is unable to compute the length in advance without buffering it.

Answer (score 4):

So no way to fix this apparently. Took a look at the code, but apparently the buffer is contructed with a default size carved into the code.

So, the only way to solve this, is to use Response::setBufferSize() from your code.

Comment: The reason why this has been downvoted is beyond me. I answered myself, provided the reason why this was not possible at the time, and provided a solution as well. Next time, please comment so that I can improve the answer, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following setting in connector: `socketBuffer="64000"`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This did not work for tomcat9 version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, set in application.properties:

server.tomcat.max-http-response-header-size=16KB # or your value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To use "socket.appWriteBufSize" and "socket.appReadBufSize" attribute, your connector must be NIO connector. Change the value of "protocol" attribute from "HTTP/1.1" to "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol".

Comment: Neither of these attributes is the response buffer size.